# My script only fetches the response from the last curl request

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to execute a curl request for each data of an array, but I actually only gets one of the answers (even if all the url are ok and the requests works one by one)

My script is as below:

```js
    tmp="{
       \"data\":{
          \"id\":\"sv-Ps7epZJypQGB4Jb3\",
          \"type\":\"state-versions\",
          \"relationships\":{
             \"outputs\":{
                \"data\":[
                   {
                      \"id\":\"wsout-YDDEzn2h9Y9fJERB\",
                      \"type\":\"state-version-outputs\"
                   },
                   {
                      \"id\":\"wsout-CYzpWK2uMDGFn9Yr\",
                      \"type\":\"state-version-outputs\"
                   },
                   {
                      \"id\":\"wsout-RroeVzLsv6PxJ56A\",
                      \"type\":\"state-version-outputs\"
                   },
                   {
                      \"id\":\"wsout-8ts3sHe7NsE46mN6\",
                      \"type\":\"state-version-outputs\"
                   }
                ]
             }
          }
       }
    }"
    echo "$tmp"
    output_ids=$(echo "${tmp}" | jq -r '.data.relationships.outputs.data[].id')
    echo "iic"
    base_url="https://app.terraform.io/api/v2/state-version-outputs/"

    declare -a tableau

    # Créez un fichier temporaire contenant le texte
    tempfile=$(mktemp)
    echo "$output_ids" > "$tempfile"

    # Parcourez chaque ligne du fichier et ajoutez-la au tableau
    while IFS= read -r ligne; do
      tableau+=("$ligne")
    done < "$tempfile"

    # Supprimez le fichier temporaire

    cat "$tempfile"
    rm "$tempfile"
    declare -p tableau


    # Accédez aux éléments du tableau
    for element in "${tableau[@]}"; do
        echo "Élément du tableau : $element"
        full_url="$base_url$element"
        echo "URL : $full_url"
        output_details=$(curl \
         --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
         --header "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" \
         -s "$full_url")
        echo "$output_details"
    done
```

and the (wrong) result:

```js
{
       "data":{
          "id":"sv-Ps7epZJypQGB4Jb3",
          "type":"state-versions",
          "relationships":{
             "outputs":{
                "data":[
                   {
                      "id":"wsout-YDDEzn2h9Y9fJERB",
                      "type":"state-version-outputs"
                   },
                   {
                      "id":"wsout-CYzpWK2uMDGFn9Yr",
                      "type":"state-version-outputs"
                   },
                   {
                      "id":"wsout-RroeVzLsv6PxJ56A",
                      "type":"state-version-outputs"
                   },
                   {
                      "id":"wsout-8ts3sHe7NsE46mN6",
                      "type":"state-version-outputs"
                   }
                ]
             }
          }
       }
    }
    wsout-YDDEzn2h9Y9fJERB
    wsout-CYzpWK2uMDGFn9Yr
    wsout-RroeVzLsv6PxJ56A
    wsout-8ts3sHe7NsE46mN6
    declare -a tableau=([0]=$'wsout-YDDEzn2h9Y9fJERB\r' [1]=$'wsout-CYzpWK2uMDGFn9Yr\r' [2]=$'wsout-RroeVzLsv6PxJ56A\r' [3]="wsout-8ts3sHe7NsE46mN6")
    Élément du tableau : wsout-YDDEzn2h9Y9fJERB
    URL : https://app.terraform.io/api/v2/state-version-outputs/wsout-YDDEzn2h9Y9fJERB

    Élément du tableau : wsout-CYzpWK2uMDGFn9Yr
    URL : https://app.terraform.io/api/v2/state-version-outputs/wsout-CYzpWK2uMDGFn9Yr

    Élément du tableau : wsout-RroeVzLsv6PxJ56A
    URL : https://app.terraform.io/api/v2/state-version-outputs/wsout-RroeVzLsv6PxJ56A

    Élément du tableau : wsout-8ts3sHe7NsE46mN6
    URL : https://app.terraform.io/api/v2/state-version-outputs/wsout-8ts3sHe7NsE46mN6
    {"data":{"id":"wsout-8ts3sHe7NsE46mN6","type":"state-version-outputs","attributes":{"name":"db_username","sensitive":false,"type":"string","value":"diagngrowdbuser","detailed-type":"string"},"links":{"self":"/api/v2/state-version-outputs/wsout-8ts3sHe7NsE46mN6"}}}
```

Thank you!

EDITED to provide a minimum reproductible version, with the results I get from execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this line of output in your question:

```
declare -a tableau=([0]=$'wsout-YDDEzn2h9Y9fJERB\r' [1]=$'wsout-CYzpWK2uMDGFn9Yr\r' [2]=$'wsout-RroeVzLsv6PxJ56A\r' [3]="wsout-8ts3sHe7NsE46mN6")
```

we can see that all of your IDs **except the last one** contain Carriage Returns (represented by `\r`), get rid of those. That's why only the last ID works and why when you hand-coded a list of IDs it also worked.

I can't use your URLs as they require the `TOKEN` in your code to be populated so here's the difference using example.com.

With a trailing CR:

```
$ url=$'https://www.example.com/index.html\r'
$ curl -s "$url"
```

we get no output while without a trailing CR:

```
$ url=$'https://www.example.com/index.html'
$ curl -s "$url" | head -3
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
```

we get the expected output.

I can't tell where the `\r` is coming from but I suspect it was added by whatever editor you used to create your code or, more likely, whatever created the file `stateVersion.json` you mentioned in a previous iteration of your question. See [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for more information on CRs and how to remove them.